# Замыкания Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, замыкания

Этот код работает в Chrome, Firefox, Opera под Windows, в Chrome и Firefox под Android - выводится цифра 5:

```js
{
  const a = 5;
  test();

  function test() {
    try {
      console.log(a);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Но в iOS 13.4.1 Safari v13.1 Mobile выдаёт ReferenceError - Can't find variable: a. Если убрать внешние скобки, то всё становится ОК.

При этом в iOS 9.3.6 Safari v9.0 Mobile и со скобками всё работает отлично.

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: в не мобильном сафари тоже воспроизводится, решается директивой `'use strict';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему в данном случае дело может быть в том, как в safari обрабатываются block-scoped функции в не строгом режиме.

Как видно из результата, они поднимаются из блока и замыкают переменные снаружи блока, то есть, если изменить код на следующий

```js
const a = 10; 
{
  const a = 5;
  test();

  function test() {
    try {
      console.log(a);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

То ошибка уйдет и будет выведено `10`.

---

Для корректной работы нужно войти в строгий режим с помощью директивы `'use strict';`

```js
'use strict';

{
  const a = 5;
  test();

  function test() {
    try {
      console.log(a);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Подробнее в ответе [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) на вопрос [What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461615/2881286)